# Setup dhcpd without gateway on purpose

Tags: ubuntu, ip, gateway, dhcp-server

I have an XP machine with two network interfaces. One is connected to my company's network (and the Internet). The other is a very local network which connects some hardware with my PC. Both the hardware and my XP machine's second network interface obtain configuration from a dhcpd running on Ubuntu in a virtual machine on my XP machine.

I entered some dummy gateway in `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` like `192.168.3.1` which does not match any existing device just to get dhcpd started. The problem is that my XP machine now tries to route Internet traffic through `192.168.3.1` in most of the cases which, of course, results in an error.

Is there any way to set up dhcpd in a way that the clients know that there is no gateway in this network?

By the way: setting the gateway manually in XP is off the table because this needs administrator privileges which I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out "option routers XX.XX.XX.XX" in your dhcpd.conf. Check the dhcpd.conf man page grouping of hosts so you can do this selectively.